# camel routes for application development

Tags: spring-boot, web-applications, apache-camel

I am thinking of developing an application with Camel Routes - with SpringBoot. the nature of application is not merely application integration but this is an application to manage security roles against ROLES/ GROUPS for Resources.
Most use cases of camel routes indicates integration. But this is a case of pure application development which includes CRUD operations (dat stored in RDBMs) on Access Information and exposing these abilities as ReST services. Could you suggest whether is the approach good.

Comment: So why exactly do you need Camel for?

Comment: I thought of using it to orchestrating calls to DB and expose ReST services.

Comment: You can pretty much do that with just spring boot (spring security, data, web, etc)... What are you missing so far that camel can provide?

Comment: the missing part is the DSL and orchestration. I am not sure whether is camel routes is an overkill in such use cases!

Answer (score 1):

I think that Camel is to big for such things. It is possible that you have more problems then advantages, because Camel use a lot of 'magic' that you don't see and need to do some research to find out how exactly some components work. The tests are another issue, you must use Camel test libraries, so you have more complexity to do the same tests.

Comment: if we are able to manage the unit test and other 'magic' stuff then it should be a good to go? The point is that the DSL mostly is self-explanatory about the program flow.

Comment: Do we have any more suggestions